# How can I improve low IOPS performance for an Azure SQL Database Hyperscale elastic pool?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm doing performance testing a series of data migration scripts which mainly consist of large INSERTs (sometimes 100M-200M records) with often complex SELECTs with a lot of hash joins.
Configuration:

- **Hyperscale: Premium-series, 16 vCores**
- Max **4TB** of Locally-redundant backup storage, however for most of the tests only ~1TB was allocated

Problem: during one of the critical queries which takes circa 2 hours and performs a 100M+ insert on a heavily indexed table (7 indexes) there seem to be extremely wild swings in IOPS write performance: [image] I set **MAXDOP=16** manually for the query (1 DOP per vCPU)

Questions:

1. My best guess is that the IOPS gets severely degraded  when the local SSD (presumably with a [maximum of 2560 IOPS per vCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tier-hyperscale)) gets filled up and the severe bottleneck becomes the shared storage instance. Is this accurate? Note that in this case this happens roughly 50% of the time and virtually everything grinds down to a halt.
2. If this is the case, is there a way to calculate the effective minimum IOPS of the shared storage instance?
3. Is there a way to improve the minimum IOPS of the shared storage instance, e.g. by manually over-allocating the storage space? (this would be the standard approach for a lot of other configurations where e.g. you get 3 IOPS per GB)
4. How can I get the actual IOPS figures rather than %?
5. Any other suggestions/tips?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [In Hyperscale, the log governance limit is set to 105 MB/sec, regardless of the service level.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/hyperscale-performance-diagnostics?view=azuresql). You're just getting swindled like everyone else.

Comment: @ErikDarling indeed, definitely a stretch to call it 'Hyperscale' but 100MB/s of log writes should probably be enough for this particular workload if it was consistent.

Comment: All of the data is sent to page servers, which have a specific size. If you "over allocate" your size, you'll get more page servers, which may help spread the load. You're still screwed with the log limits and how fast the page servers can ingest the log. I wouldn't call 100 MB/sec very fast for hundreds of millions of writes into a heavily indexed table, but then again it's relative given how bad cloud performance is.